# Datatable's Compute Function For Rows

Tags: asp.net, datatable

As we know that, with compute function of datatable we can get sum of columns. 
But I want to get sum of a row of datatable.
I will explain with a example:

I have a datatable like image below: With compute function we can get the sum of each column (product). Such as for product1, 2 + 12 + 50 + 13= 77.

I want to get sum of company1 : 2 + 6 + 4 + 3 + 5 = 20

http://img123.imageshack.us/img123/1517/61519307xx5.jpg

How can I do it with asp.net 1.1?

Comment: Wow, you really are in the stone ages! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LINQ to the rescue:**

```
DataTable dt = WhateverCreatesDataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
int sum = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Sum(dc=>(int)dr[dc]);
```

For those still dragging their knuckles in the stone ages (aka pre-.Net 3.5 and LINQ):

```
DataTable dt = WhateverCreatesDataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
int sum = 0;

foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
  sum += (int)dr[dc];
```

Comment: Then put that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx):

> If you must perform an operation on
>   two or more columns, you should create
>   a DataColumn, set its Expression
>   property to an appropriate expression,
>   and use an aggregate expression on the
>   resulting column. In that case, given
>   a DataColumn with the name "total",
>   and the Expression property set to
>   this:
>
> `"Quantity * UnitPrice"`

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to solve this in 1.1 here is what you can do as a simple solution

```
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
totalColumn.ColumnName = "Total";
totalColumn.Expression = "Product1 + Product2 + Product3 + Product4 + Product5";

// Populate and get the DataTable dt then add this computed column to this table

dt.Columns.Add(totalColumn);
//Now if you access the column "Total" of the table you will get the desired result.
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Datatable's Compute() function for the following purpose:

- To find sum.
- To find max value.
- To find min value.
- To calculate average.

Below links have detailed explaination of Datatable's compute() function:

http://codevariation.blogspot.com/2017/02/using-datatable-compute-function-in-cnet.html

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.